# Cómo confiar en certificado SSL auto-firmado

Tags: php, webservice, soap

He desarrollado un cliente en php utilizando Soap para un webservice desarrollado en .net. Este webservice utiliza https con un certificado auto-firmado y para las pruebas debo confiar en el certificado sin instalarlo.

El problema es que siempre obtengo este error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?wsdl"
```

Este es el código de la llamada:

```
    $opts = [
        'ssl' => [
            // set some SSL/TLS specific options
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
        ],
         'http'=>[
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        ]
    ];

    // Initialize Soap Client
    $this->client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,  'location' => 'https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc','stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts), 'exceptions' => true, 'trace' => true));
```

Answer (score 1):

La URL `https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?wsdl` no está disponible. Es posible que sea, como indica, que no puede leer la definición. Verifica primero que la URL del webservice sea accesible desde tu servidor.

Verificada la URL, podrías probar deshabilitando la validación del certificado añadiendo a `$opts` los parámetros `'verifypeer'=>false` y `'verifyhost'=>false`.

Tengo entendido que los parámetros de SSL no afectan a la descarga del WSDL, al menos hasta php 7. He hecho algunas pruebas y posiblemente sea ese el problema. Deberías mantener deshabilitada la opción de validación de certificados para el consumo del webservice, pero con respecto al WSDL, te podría sugerir no usarlo (`null` en el primer parámetro de `new SoapClient`) o bien descargarlo, subirlo al servidor y usar el archivo local.

Comment: Hola Gabriel, en los navegadores Chrome y Firefox no se puede visualizar la wsdl, al menos yo no he podido, pero sí en Internet Explorer o Opera lo que demuestra que sí está activo. Gracias igualmente :)

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: Hola Gabriel, he añadido los parámetros y sigue sin funcionar, sin embargo he sido capaz de obtener la wsdl mediante wget `wget --secure-protocol=SSLv3  https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?wsdl --no-check-certificate`, por lo que también he añadido el parámetro `'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3` pero sin suerte.

Comment: ¿Versión de php?

Comment: Utilizo gentoo con php 5.6.23

Comment: He actualizado nuevamente la respuesta.

Comment: Nada... He descargado el archivo WSDL pero importa otros ficheros del webservice y pasa lo mismo. También lo he intentado como me has indicado poniendo el parámetro a null, pero al hacer cualquier llamada me da el siguiente error `Could not connect to host`. Muchas gracias por tu apoyo.